# True/False: Questions from Anton Howard's Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I'm a high schooler taking linear algebra this year and have two false and true questions that I'm struggling to prove.

Here are my questions,

a) If $AA^{\top}$ is singular, then so is $A$.

b) If $A+B$ is symmetric, then so are $A$ and $B$.

I tried to use $A+B=(A+B)^{\top}=A^{\top}+B^{\top}$ for the second one. but I am stuck with proving if $A+B=A^{\top}+B^{\top}$，then $A=A^{\top}$ and $B=B^{\top}$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

For (a), what are you using as the definition of singular? One way to go is to note that $\det{(AA^{\top})} = \det{(A)}\det{(A^{\top})} = \det{(A)}\det{(A)} = \left[\det{(A)}\right]^{2}$, so $\det{(AA^{\top})} = 0$ if and only if $\det{(A)} = 0$.

For (b), let $A$ be any non-symmetric matrix and let $B = -A$. Then $A+B$ is the zero matrix, which is symmetric, but $A$ and $B$ aren't symmetric.

Comment: For (a), I'm using "non-invertible" as the definition of singular. I thought det(A $ A^T $ )=det(A)det( $A^T$ ) only works if A is a square matrix. But my question doesn't told A is a rectangular matrix or a square matrix.

Comment: @YeeLin Only square matrices are invertible, so I think usually "singular" means a "non-invertible *square* matrix." Anyway, if $A$ is not square, then (a) holds easily because $A$ is always non-invertible and it doesn't matter if $AA^{T}$ is invertible or not. Then you can prove the case where $A$ is square using determinants.